# Animation Node - How to create a crazy spray of hexagon shapes?

Tags: animation-nodes

Today, I saw this video of someone's work at Gfycat. It uses Sverchok nodes. 
Now, I wonder how to create that with the Animation Nodes. Thanks in advance. 
This is for future projects with motion graphics.

[image]

Comment: Hi. What have you got so far and where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: I'm only few months learning Animation Nodes, but I don't know where to start, how to randomise sizes during animation.

Comment: The reason I ask is that this site is for *specific* questions, with *specific* answers. Questions like yours can come across a bit "do this effect for me" (though I'm sure that wasn't your intent). I would break the problem down into the parts you can and can't do and ask questions based on those specific parts. E.g. "How can I give objects a random size?" would be a better question as it is about a specific process (though, ideally you should still attempt it). So, you might want to use the [edit] link below your question to refine it to something more specific.

Comment: I agree with Ray. Look at the questions you asked so far, a lot of the questions you asked—and I answered—share very similar answers. So ideally, you could have found a solution yourself by studying similar questions and spending sometime on finding a solution. Now, I answered your questions and will continue to do so, part of the reason why I don't write comments such as this, is because I don't want readers to feel discouraged to ask questions or contribute. AN in particular have this "It is hard to use", "there is no tutorials" vibe. Which is why I dedicated myself to the AN tag.

Comment: Omar, I agree with "It is hard to use" and "there is no tutorials" stuff. AN is just challenging and complex and I know just roughly 10 nodes of AN. I keep scrapbooks for perusing others' node works: they are for study purpose only.

Comment: @RayMairlot, I thank you for suggestions. Next time, I will be more specific in my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a *Delay Falloff* node with an *Offset Matrix* node. The offset translation vectors should be the inverse of the location vectors, this translates vectors to the origin point. A *Shuffle List* node is used to randomize the indices of the matrices and consequently randomize the the falloff delay. From all of this, the implementation is as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

A honeycomb distribution can be created as described [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/936).

Comment: This is great and you are a genius. Many thanks. I see many uses for your nodes in future. BTW, I always recognise your style of node compositing from anywhere, before ever looking at your name. You are just one of the fewest being so neat and tidy at aligning nodes. It is quick and easy to read them, when they are close together.

Comment: This node work looks too complex and challenge for learning, but I will figure all out in time, as I learn usage of each node. I learn by perusing examples like yours. Thanks for this, Omar.